# Sending HTML text message to a phone in java

Tags: java, html, email, jakarta-mail

I currently have a program that sends users an email based on their information in my database. The email is built out in html and sends to the users email as a content type text/html. I want to try and see if I could somehow send this message to their phone using the email format ##########@domain.com.

Obviously phones cant receive an HTML message, so I tried this:

-Removed the html and sent pure text, this did work, however for Verizon (the only service provider I tested) the text got cut off and the full message never sent. I only received the first part of the message.

Then I wondered if it was possible to somehow "screenshot" the html message and simply send the picture of the html display to the phone.

Here is my current code to send an email:

```
public static void email(String content, String address) {

    final String username = "email";
    final String password = "password";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });

    try {


            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            Address[] a = InternetAddress.parse("myemail");
            message.setReplyTo(a);
            message.setHeader("From: ", "Movie Alert");
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(address));

            if (ShowFinder.showsFound > 1) message.setSubject("Movie Alert: " + ShowFinder.showsFound + " New Shows Found!");
            else if (ShowFinder.showsFound == 1) message.setSubject("Movie Alert: " + ShowFinder.showsFound + " New Show Found!");
            else message.setSubject("Unsubscribed");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(content);
            message.setContent(sb.toString(), "text/html");

            Transport.send(message);


        System.out.println("Sent Email");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

So in conclusion I have the following questions:

-Is the reason the text got cut off because I am not sending the email properly, or because of the service provider?

-Is it possible to send a screenshot of the html display based on the html code through a text message?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried text/plain instead of text/html?  Or just use `setText(sb.toString())`

Comment: I tried using the setText and text/plain and I get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to send an html message to a phone! There is a jar called HTML2Image that will convert your html code into an image: https://code.google.com/p/java-html2image/

To make an image of the html you would do something like this:

```
    HtmlImageGenerator imageGenerator = new HtmlImageGenerator();
    imageGenerator.loadHtml("<b>Hello World!</b> Please goto <a title=\"Goto Google\" href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>.");
    imageGenerator.saveAsImage("hello-world.png");
```

Then you could send this new image like so:

```
                    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
            MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("email"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(toEmail));
            mbp1.setText(text);
                    mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);

            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(new File("screenshot location/hello-world.png"));
                mbp2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                mbp2.setFileName("Screenshot.png");
                mbp2.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image_cid>");
            mp.addBodyPart(mbp2);

            message.setContent(mp);
            Transport.send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect the text is getting cut off because of the service provider.  There's probably a limit on the size of a single text message.

If you can't fit all the text you want into a short message, you might want to send a link to a web page containing all the information.